# Variable not Updating, While Loop not working

Tags: c, while-loop, switch-statement, hex, octal

I am working on an accumulator that asks for different inputs and based on those inputs, updates values in an accumulator. My loop however, doesn't seem to run when I ask for a decimal, hexadecimal, or octal to be inputed. Could someone possibly take a look and give some suggestions to fix it? Thank you! Also Im suppose to somehow use a while loop in my print_menu() function that will check is the input is valid. Any suggestions?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
short get_operand(char mode);
void print_acc(short acc);
char print_menu(void);
int main(void);

int main(){
  char mode = 'D';
  short acc = 8;
  char input[10];
  char option;
  char valid_input[7] = "OHDCSQ";

  while (mode != 'Q'){
      print_acc(acc);
      print_menu();
      scanf("%s", &input);
      printf("%s\n", input);
      option = (char) toupper(input[0]);

  switch(option){
      case 'O':
          mode = 'O';
          printf("mode\n");
          printf("Mode is Octal\n");
          break;

      case 'H':
          mode = 'H';
          printf("Mode is Hexadecimal\n");
          break;

      case 'D':
          mode = 'D';
          printf("Mode is Decimal\n");
          break;

      case 'C':
          acc = 0;
          break;

      case 'S':

          get_operand(mode);
          if (mode == 'H'){
              scanf("%hx", &acc);
              printf("%hx", acc);
              print_acc(acc);
          }

          else if (mode == 'O'){
              scanf("%ho", &acc);
              printf("%ho", acc);
              print_acc(acc);

          }
          else{
               scanf("%hd", &acc);
               printf("%hd", acc);
               print_acc(acc);
          }

      case 'Q':
         mode = 'Q';
         printf("\n");
         break;

    }
    //return acc;
   }


}
void print_acc(short acc){
      printf("\n");
      printf("****************************************\n");
      printf("* Accumulator:                         *\n");
      printf("*   Hex     :   %04hx                   *\n", acc);
      printf("*   Octal   :   %08ho               *\n", acc);
      printf("*   Decimal :   %06hd                      *\n", acc);
      printf("****************************************\n");

}

char print_menu(void){
      printf("\n");
      printf("Please Select one of the following options:\n");
      printf("O Octal Mode\n");
      printf("H Hecadecimal Mode\n");
      printf("D Decimal Mode\n");
      printf("\n");
      printf("C Clear Accumulator\n");
      printf("S Set Accumulator\n");
      printf("\n");
      printf("Q Quit\n");
      printf("\n");
      printf("Option: ");

}

short get_operand(char mode){
   switch(mode){
      case 'H':
          printf("Enter Hex value:");

          break;
      case 'O':
          printf("Enter Octal value:");
          break;
      default:
          printf("Enter decimal value: ");
          break;
   }
   return mode;
}
```

Comment: Step 1 `scanf("%s", &input);` --> `scanf("%9s", input);`  2) What was your input?

Comment: 1) `get_operand` should return a `char`

2) you forgot `mode = get_operand(mode)` to actually set the mode. also you forgot a break before `case 'Q'` and you can use a switch statement inside the `case 'S'` whenever that makes sense (do it after everything else works)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `'S'` case where you read in a number, you forget to add a `break` statement at the end of the case.  This results in the code *falling through* to the `Q` case which causes the loop to exit.

Add the `break` and the loop will continue as expected:

```
  case 'S':
      ...
      break;
  case 'Q':
      ...
```

This is also incorrect:

```
scanf("%s", &input);
```

`%s` expects a `char *`, but you're passing the address of an array (a `char (*)[10]` to be presice).  Pass in the array directly, which will decay to a pointer to the first element to yield the correct type:

```
scanf("%s", input);
```

Also, change `print_menu` and `get_operand` to return `void`, since you're not using the return value and in the former case failing to include one.